# Calculate e^x without inbuilt functions in Java

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java and currently going through the "how to think like a computer scientist" beginners book. I am stuck with a problem in the iteration chapter. Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

When I use math.exp, I get an answer that is completely different from the answer my code obtains. 
Note, it's not homework.

Here's the question:

> One way to calculate e<sup>x</sup> is to use the infinite series expansion
>   e<sup>x</sup> = 1 + x + x<sup>2</sup> /2! + x<sup>3</sup>/3! + x<sup>4</sup>/4! +`...`
>   If the loop variable is named `i`, then the ith term is x<sup>`i`</sup>/`i`!.
>
> 1. Write a method called `myexp` that adds up the first `n` terms of this
>      series.

So here's the code:

```
public class InfiniteExpansion {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner infinite = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("what is the  value of X?");
        double x = infinite.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("what is the power?");
        int power = infinite.nextInt();



        System.out.println(Math.exp(power));//for comparison

        System.out.println("the final value of series is: "+myExp(x, power));
    }

    public static double myExp(double myX, double myPower){

        double firstResult = myX;
        double denom = 1;
        double sum =myX;

        for(int count =1;count<myPower;count++){

            firstResult = firstResult*myX;//handles the numerator

            denom = denom*(denom+1);//handles the denominator

            firstResult = firstResult/denom;//handles the segment

            sum =sum+firstResult;// adds up the different segments
        }

        return (sum+1);//gets the final result
    }

}
```

Comment: `firstResult = firstResult*myX;` and `firstResult = firstResult/denom;` both modify the same variable one after the other, is that intentional?

Comment: Yes it is. The firstResult = firstResult*myX line handles the numerator part e.g like the x^2 in x^2/2!. The firstResult = firstResult/denom; line uses the value of the previous first result, divides it with the denominator and gets the whole value of e.g x^2/2!. I don't know if i've cleared it up...

Comment: @Peter O. Thanks for the (very many) corrections.

Answer (score 4):

The assignment `denom = denom*(denom+1)` is going to give a sequence as follows: `1, 1*2=2, 2*3=6, 6*7=42, 42*43=...`
But you want `denom = denom*count`.

Let's say in general we just want to print the first `n` factorials starting with `1!`: `1!, 2!, 3!, ..., n!`. At the `k`th term, we take the `k-1`th term and multiply by `k`. That would be computing `k!` recursively on the previous term. Concrete examples: `4!` is `3!` times `4`, `6!` is `5!` times `6`.

In code, we have

```
var n = 7;
var a = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++ ) {
    a = a*i; // Here's the recursion mentioned above.
    System.out.println(i+'! is '+a);
}
```

Try running the above and compare to see what you get with running the following:

```
var n = 7;
var a = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++ ) {
    a = a*(a+1);
    System.out.println('Is '+i+'! equal to '+a+'?');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't seen that. Could you help me with the logic? I just don't see where i am going wrong...:(

Comment: I have updated my answer to try and help with the logic.

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors here:

1. firstResult should start from 1, so that it goes 1+x+x^2 instead of 1+x^2+x^3
2. As timctran stated you are not calculating the factorial in a correct way.

To wrap up you can simplify your operations to:

```
firstResult = firstResult * myX / (count+1);
sum += firstResult;
```

Edit:
 - I ran the code and saw that Math.exp(power) is printed instead of Math.exp(x)
 - My first item is wrong since sum is initialized to myX.

Comment: I get the denominator thing. The reason why i made firstResult equal to myX instead of 1 is so that if x (the power) is 1, the for loop would be skipped and the returned result would be the 1+x part. Now, if the power is 2, the new value of firstResult would be firstResult squared because of firstResult = firstResult*myX;. The program would loop for myPower-1 because the the initial value of firstResult i.e (< as opposed to <=). So, could you please rephrase because i don't seem to be understanding the first point? Thank you

Comment: You are right, I didn't see that you have initialized your sum with myX.

Comment: I've divided, the right hand part into two; I first use the myExp method to calculate the x + x2 /2! + x3/3! + x4/4! +... part. The method returns 1 plus the value already obtained.

Comment: In that case, you have to change count to (count+1) as you are starting from x^2/2!. Also, you are printing Math.exp(power) instead of Math.exp(x) in your main function.

Answer (score 0):

Why make it complicated? I tried a solution and it looks like this:

```
//One way to calculate ex is to use the infinite series expansion 
//ex = 1 + x + x2 /2! + x3/3! + x4/4! +... 
//If the loop variable is named i, then the ith term is xi/i!.
//
//Write a method called myexp that adds up the first n terms of this series.
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InfiniteExpansion2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner infinite = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("what is the  value of X?");
        double x = infinite.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("what is the value of I?");  // !
        int power = infinite.nextInt();

        System.out.println(Math.exp(power));//for comparison

        System.out.println("the final value of series is: " + myCalc(x, power));
    }

    public static double fac(double myI) {
        if (myI > 1) {
            return myI * fac(myI - 1);
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public static double exp(double myX, double myE) {
        double result;
        if (myE == 0) {
            result = 1;
        } else {
            result = myX;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < myE; i++) {
            result *= myX;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static double myCalc(double myX, double myI) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= myI; i++) { // x^0 is 1
            sum += (exp(myX, i) / fac(i));
        }
        return sum;
    }

}
```

If you want to think like an engineer, I'd do it like this:

- keep it simple
- break it into pieces
- stick closely to the task (like I named the var myI, not myPower - seems clearer to me, for a start - that way you won't get confused)

I hope you like it!

Comment: Thanks for the response but i am not to use any inbuilt math methods. I think it's a meant to make one practice logic as opposed to getting the right answer

Comment: "I think it's a meant to make one practice logic as opposed to getting the right answer" - I think you're right! You have two things in my solution: 1. breaking things up, 2. two different sorts of programming concepts: a recursion and a loop.

Comment: Sorry, I had some errors in it - another important rule: Write unit tests!!! That way you find errors faster. I should have done that from the beginning. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I tried a solution and it looks like this:

```
public class Fact {

    public int facto(int n){
            if(n==0)
                return 1;
            else
                return n*facto(n-1);
        }
    }

}
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ex {

public static void main(String[] args){

        Fact myexp=new Fact();

        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=1;

        double e=1,i=0,x;
        int j=1;
        System.out.println("Enter n: ");
        n=input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter x: ");
        x=input.nextDouble();
        while(j<=n)
        {
            int a=myexp.facto(j);
            double y=Math.pow(x,j)/(double)a;

            i=i+y;
            ++j;
        }       

        e=e+i;
        System.out.println("e^x= "+ e);

    }
}
```